# Should we check CSRF token for read only actions

Tags: web, csrf

I have heard many people suggest that CSRF handling is mandatory for actions performing write operations but its optional for action performing read only operations?

If yes please share an example how action which only performs read only operations can be exploited using CSRF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily [safe methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-22) do not have to be protected against CSRF because they do not make changes to the application (i.e they are "read only" as you state in your question), and even if they're returning sensitive information this will be protected by the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in the browser.

If your site is implemented as per standards, your GET requests should be safe and therefore do not need protection.

However, there is a specific case where a "Cross-Site DoS"<sup>*</sup> attack could be executed. Say your reporting page takes 10 seconds to execute, with 100% CPU usage on your database server, and 80% CPU usage on your web server.

Users of your website know never to go to `https://yoursite.example.org/Analysis/GetReport` during office hours because it kills the server and gives other users a bad user experience.

However, [Chuck](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/dd/9b/e7/dd9be748b39c2ee35b7f09c72efb3053.jpg) wants to knock your `yoursite.example.org` website offline because he doesn't like you or your company.

On the busy forum that your company employees frequent, `http://forum.walkertexasranger.example.com`, he sets his signature to the following:

```
<img src="https://yoursite.example.org/Analysis/GetReport" width=0 height=0 />
```

Every time one of Chuck's posts are read by your employees, authentication cookies are sent to `https://yoursite.example.org/Analysis/GetReport`, so your site processes the request and generates the report, and  your system goes offline because CPU is eaten by these constant requests.

So even though the request is a GET request and doesn't make any permanent changes to your system (aka "safe"/"read only"), it is in fact bringing down your system every time it is ran. Therefore, it would be better to protect this with a CSRF prevention method and maybe implement as a POST.

<sup>*XSDoS, or Cross-Site Denial if Service, is a phrase coined by me, so don't go Googling for it.</sup>